# concatenate element name with attribute name in jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass an attribute value to radio name in order to distinguish between different radio groups in my page:

```
$("input:radio[name=myRadio+$(this).attr('data-id')]").change(function() {      
      //my code....
});
```

But i get some syntax error, please help with the correct syntax

Comment: Can we get your html code?

Comment: Yarin Levi it's a syntax error in the jquery statement nothing to do with html

Comment: I got it. but how can I know which element you want to catch? You have an error and maybe it is because of your HTML element names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation syntax is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
$('input:radio[name="myRadio' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').on('change', function() {      
  // your code...
});
```

Or in ES6:

```
$(`input:radio[name="myRadio${$(this).data('id')}"]`).on('change', function() {      
  // your code...
});
```

Better yet, don't build selectors at runtime. Use common classes to group elements by structure, along with DOM traversal methods to relate them to each other when events occur.